# Bootstrap Typeahead AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a modified version of typeahead for Twitter Bootstrap (https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead), which simplifies using remote data. The problem I've run into is that my AJAX call url depends on the selected option in my select input.

```
var subjectId = $('#chapters-open-subject option:selected').val();      
    $('#chapters-edit-title').typeahead({
        onSelect: function(item){
            $('#chapters-edit-submit').attr('disabled',false).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
        },
        ajax: {
            url: '/admin/misc/chapters/search/'+subjectId
        },
        displayField: 'naslov'
    });
```

The problem is that even though I change the option in my select box, the url in AJAX request stays the same and is not changed accordingly.
How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your expression is only evaluated once, and the URL that is passed to the typeahead library is based on the value of `subjectId` when that code is executed.  Put another way, in order for what you've written to work, all of this code would have to be executed every time the value of the `#chapters-open-subject` select changes.

Comment: Do you maybe have any suggestions on how to do so?

Comment: Sure, just wrap the whole block of code there in `$('#chapers-open-subject').on('change', function() {` *(your code here)* `});`.  This might be a bad idea though, if the library can't handle being called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to get away with something like this:

```
var subjectId = $('#chapters-open-subject option:selected').val();

var $typeahead = $('#chapters-edit-title').typeahead({
    onSelect: function(item){
        $('#chapters-edit-submit').attr('disabled',false).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
    },
    ajax: {
        url: '/admin/misc/chapters/search/' + subjectId
    },
    displayField: 'naslov'
});

$('#chapters-open-subject').on('change', function() {
    subjectId = $(this).val();
    $typeahead.data('typeahead').options.ajax.url = '/admin/misc/chapters/search/' + subjectId;
});
```

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest posting an issue with the library on GitHub.  It does not seem to have the capability to change the URL easily after it is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
ajax : 
{
  preDispatch : function() { return { q: $("#subjectId").val() }},
  url: '/admin/misc/chapters/search/'+ ,
  method : 'get',
  displayField : 'naslov',
}
```